# Почему вёрстка съезжает на пару пикселей?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

[image: иллюстрация верстки]

Верстаю по макету, соблюдаю все размеры, как в макете прописано. В результате `margin: 25px` между рядами к третьему ряду съезжает на пару пикселей. Может ли это быть из-за особенностей браузера (Chrome)? Критичен ли такой сдвиг в реальных проектах?

```css
html {
  background-color: #CFD0CF;
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 47px;
  font: 42px 'Arial', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #434344;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

}

 ul {
  display: block;
  width: 595px;
  margin: 0 auto; 

  overflow: visible;
   perspective: 600px;

}




input {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

li {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  perspective: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.card-front {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(34, 171, 147, 1) 0%, 
rgba(25, 102, 141, 1) 100%);
}

.card-back {
  font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  line-height: 120px;

}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.5);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~.card-front {
  perspective-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

input:checked~.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
<h1>Memoji</h1>
</header>
<main>
<section class="cards">
<ul>

  <li  id='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c1'> <label for="c1" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"></div>
  </li>
  <li  id='2'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c2'> <label for="c2" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back">  </div>
  </li>
  <li  id='3'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c3'> <label for="c3" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back">  </div>
  </li>
  <li  id='4'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c4'> <label for="c4" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back">  </div>
  </li>
  <li  id='5'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c5'> <label for="c5" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back">   </div>
  </li>
  <li id='6'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c6'> <label for="c6" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"> </div>
  </li>
  <li id='7'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c7'> <label for="c7" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"></div>
  </li>
  <li id='8'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c8'> <label for="c8" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"> </div>
  </li>
  <li  id='9'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c9'> <label for="c9" 
class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"> </div>
  </li>
  <li  id='10'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c10'> <label 
for="c10" class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"></div>
  </li>
  <li id='11'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c11'> <label 
for="c11" class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"> </div>
  </li>
  <li id='12'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='c12'> <label 
for="c12" class="card-front"></label>

    <div class="card-back"></div>
  </li>



</ul>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: «соблюдаю все размеры» — верить на слово не хотим, код в студию

Comment: @andreymal Код:                                                                                                                         ` `li {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  perspective: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}`

Comment: В текст вопроса вместе с html-кодом и воспроизводимым примером, пожалуйста

Comment: При запуске данного css-кода в Chrome всё четко и ровно в соответствии с макетом https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i7VN.png (с поправкой на чудовищное сжатие вашей картинки)

Comment: Запустил ваш код в Chrome, сделал скриншот и измерил высоту элементов — получил ровно 130+25+130+25+130 = 440 пикселей в абсолютном соответствии с размерами, указанными на макете: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfXTN.png — о каких смещениях вы говорите, по-прежнему не понятно

Comment: @andreymal а вот у меня и код из вашего fiddle примера съезжает. https://imgur.com/KIWmBYM по такой же схеме: первые два совпадают, а дальше кто в лес кто по дрова

Comment: Как я уже сказал, по линейке там ровно 440 пикселей и ничего не съезжает. У вас съезжает не хром, а сам макет

Comment: @andreymal Да, значит в макете проблема. Спасибо

Comment: @Nancy T Проще изменить структуру и технику, если у вас что-то съезжает. Вам ведь строгая геометрия нужна. Я могу сделать.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev Что вы имеете ввиду под структурой и техникой?

Comment: @Nancy T где съезжает, покажите мне скрин и метку. Структора и техника - расположение тэгов и использование как их порядок, количество + стили. Кратко: ведь такое можно сделать несколькими вариантами.